# Why is double free called in this situation?

Tags: c++, boost

I've come about with the following situation that I fortunately solved by refactoring some other code, not related to the actual issue which I managed to capture below.

The code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

void passIocPtr(__attribute__((unused)) std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> iocPtr)
{}

void makeptr(boost::asio::io_context* ioc)
{
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> iocPtr = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_context>();
    iocPtr.reset(ioc);
    passIocPtr(iocPtr);
}

void makeptr2(boost::asio::io_context* ioc)
{
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> iocPtr(ioc);
    passIocPtr(iocPtr);
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    // makeptr(ioc);
    makeptr2(ioc);
}
```

Both functions (`makeptr` and `makeptr2`) would result in:

double free or corruption (out) / free(): invalid pointer

The code I was working on had to use a pointer to a io_context.
Not entirely sure if the issue I had is specifically related to the ioc, I think it's pretty much my bad usage of smart pointers.

Maybe someone can give me some insight on how I should approach this better.

Comment: Because the `ioc` you're trying to put in a `shared_ptr` just __isn't__ a shared resource.

Comment: You're giving shared_ptr the address of a local variable. shared_ptr runs `delete` when there aren't any shared_ptrs left. See the problem?

Comment: The code doesn't compile, so it's hard to tell really. But if I add `&` and `*` in relevant places, there are two issues - you create `std::shared_ptr` with default deleter from a pointer not allocated by `new` (which will try to `delete` an object on the stack) and you create two unrelated `std::shared_ptr`s to the same resource (which will try to `delete` the same thing twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is exclusively for managing heap objects

here:

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
 //    makeptr(ioc);
    makeptr2(ioc);
}
```

you are passing a stack object to `shared_ptr` (eventually in make_ptr2). All bets are off after that. The double free message really means 'whoa - you have trashed your heap'

If you want this to work put ioc on the heap

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context *ioc = new boost::asio::io_context;
    // makeptr(ioc);
    makeptr2(ioc);
}
```

Comment: Oh this is almost painfully obvious. Also explains why I was seeing this only in a unit test.
Thanks a lot!